# Get me down to / Take me down to

Tags: grammar

The context is when you take a taxi and want to ask the driver to go to city center, Which one is correct :

> 1) Get me down to city center.
>
> 2) Take me down to city center.

Comment: There is sort of a weird aspect to this. When you say "down to the city center" it implies to me that you are north of the city center. "Downtown" refers to the city center, so you could say "please take me downtown" regardless of what direction the city center was. Also a taxi driver would realistically want a specific spot within the downtown area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are other bits of your examples that sound unnatural or ungrammatical, you can use these almost interchangeably:

> Please take me to this address.
> Please get me to this address.

The "get me to" construction sounds more urgent, but the "take me to" construction is more polite.

Comment: The "get me to" construction isn't wrong, but it sounds coarse to me. I'd always use the "take me to" style.

Comment: @MaxW I'd always prefer the "take me to" style, too, short of an extreme emergency! _Please get me to the hospital! My mother is dying._ I think there are rude people who just believe all their time is really that important, though. Of course, most of them probably wouldn't say "please," either.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither of the examples you posted are perfectly grammatical. Though, to tell you the truth, they almost pass as valid English. Your biggest mistake was that you forgot to put the *the* before *city center*. Here are a fixed version of your first example and two more possible ways to tell the taxi driver that you want to go to the city center:

> Take me down to **the** city center, please.
>
> Take me to **the** city center, please.
>
> Please, take me downtown.

Notice that there is no *the* in front of *downtown*. That's because *downtown* is not used as a noun here, but as an adverb.

Comment: Both of your examples use "take." There's nothing wrong with "Please get me to the city center," either.

Comment: I'm not saying that they're wrong. The only thing I'm saying is that there's a minor grammar problem in both of the original examples.

Comment: And you are obviously correct! I just think the difference between "take me" and "get me" may go more to the heart of the question. I posted another answer, though, so we'll see. :)